# windows service (with timer) not working without console

Tags: c#, .net, console, windows-services, system.timers.timer

I make a windows service with Timers.Timer.
If i run as console app works fine, but if I change setting as windows app and  I comment all Console functions, the timer not working. with Console.ReadLine(); all good. but I dont should open console.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        AutoLog = false;
        SetTimer();
        Console.ReadLine();//if remove this line dont works
    }
```

SetTimer()

```
private void SetTimer()
    {
        mytimer = new Timer();
        mytimer.Interval = 2000;
        mytimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        mytimer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

OnTimedEvent()

```
 private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        mytimer.Enabled = false;
        EventLog evento1 = new EventLog();
        evento1.Source = "scPublicar";
        evento1.Log = "Publicar";
        evento1.WriteEntry("Publicación corriendo,  OnTimedEvent");
        mytimer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Program.cs Main()

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceBase[] servicesToRun;
        servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Publicar() };
        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
        {
            MethodInfo onStartMethod = typeof(ServiceBase).GetMethod("OnStart", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            foreach (ServiceBase service in servicesToRun)
            {
                onStartMethod.Invoke(service, new object[] { new string[] { } });
            }
        }
        else
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
    }
```

Thanks for yours answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run / debug your code in Visual Studio then `Environment.UserInteractive` is `true` and the process stops right away. This behaviour is by design and you should not do something to make it wait (e.g. call `Console.ReadLine()`).

You need to run your code as a Windows service (instead of a console application) and then it will be managed by the Services Control Manager. This means that you can configure it to start automatically at system startup and to keep running. You can also start and stop it via the Services Snap-In in the Windows Management Console (`services.msc`). But for this to work you first need to install your service.

Follow these steps:

1. [Create a new 'Windows Service' project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-create-windows-services). You will notice that the output type is already set to 'Windows Application'.
2. Paste your code into the new `Program.cs` file and remove the `Console.ReadLine()` statement
3. [Add an installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-add-installers-to-your-service-application)
4. [Install the service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer#installing-the-service)
5. Run `services.msc`. You should find a service called 'Service1'. Right-click on it to start it.
6. Go to the event log and you will find an entry every 2 seconds

References:

- [Introduction to Windows Service Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications)
- [How to: Create Windows Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications)

Comment: You're right.
If I install the service, it works fine.
I was looking a way to test without install but it's fine for me.
Thanks so much.